# Pod deployment issue and query over Kubernetes cluster

Tags: docker, kubernetes, kubernetes-pod

I have created a k8s cluster and network, using 1 master and 2 nodes. However during pod (nginx) deployment, the deployment happens only on one server i.e. node1 and not on other server i.e. node2, as the result shows below o/p

```
[root@controller Kubernetes]# kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME    READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP            NODE    NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
nginx   1/1     Running   0          10m   192.168.1.2   node1   <none>           <none>
[root@controller Kubernetes]#
```

which means nginx is deployed on only node1 and not on node2

Result of the nodes joining the master

```
NAME         STATUS   ROLES    AGE    VERSION   INTERNAL-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   OS-IMAGE                KERNEL-VERSION               CONTAINER-RUNTIME
controller   Ready    master   142m   v1.16.0   192.168.33.20   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
node1        Ready    <none>   134m   v1.16.0   192.168.33.10   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
node2        Ready    <none>   46m    v1.16.0   192.168.33.30   <none>        CentOS Linux 7 (Core)   3.10.0-1062.1.1.el7.x86_64   docker://1.13.1
[root@controller Kubernetes]#
```

Pod file:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
     name: nginx-web-application

spec:
  containers:
    - name: nginx-container
      image: nginx
```

I want to see the deployment happening on node2 as well when i run below command, can u please tell why it is not happening on both the nodes:

```
kubectl create -f pod.yml
```

Answer (score 2):

Your setup creates a pod with one container on one of the nodes (which one is decided by [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-scheduler)).

If you want to run that pod on each node use [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/) which ensures that a copy of a pod runs on each node.

[Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/#creating-a-deployment) with 2 or more replicas should work since you have two nodes if both of your nodes are capable of running that pod (look at [kube-scheduler](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/overview/components/#kube-scheduler)).

And last thing - you can use [Taints and Tolerations](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/taint-and-toleration/). Easiest way would be to taint your `node1` to not allow shceduling pods on it (example from the documentation):

```
kubectl taint nodes node1 key:NoSchedule-
```

Answer (score 1):

A Pod is exactly one copy of a container (rarely, multiple tightly-coupled containers).  It will run on exactly one node.

You almost never want to directly use a Pod; instead, prefer a higher-level controller object.  Most often you'll use a [Deployment](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/deployment/), which you can tell you want *e.g.* 3 replicas of a pod running somewhere in the cluster.  If you actually need one copy running on each node (usually this is only needed for infrastructure-type pods) that's the model of a [DaemonSet](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/daemonset/).

Comment: I an rephrasing my earlier comment, as we know on every node there can be multiple pods, each pod can contain multiple containers, and I can say on the node1 the 'nginx' container is running (which i can see in my current setup). So so should the nginx service be running on the server or inside the container, can you pls clarify.